# SSH commands from script to remote server not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix, networking, ssh

Greeting All,

I have following query and would appreciate any help on this.Thanks.

## Scenario :

My local server (server-A) is connected to one remote server (server-B).Server-B is connected to 10 other remote servers (Server-C...Server-L). 
Server-A is not directly connected to (Server-C...Server-L) ,its only connected through Server-B.

I have managed to do SSH key pairing between:

```
Server-A <----> Server-B
Server-B <----> Server-C....Server-L
```

So now I can login into Server-C from Server-A using below command:

From Server-A :

```
 ssh user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t ssh user-c@(IP-Server-C)
 ssh -t user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t scp  -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no test.file user-c@(IP-Server-C):/home/user-C
```

## Here is my actual script: (Running from Server-A)

```
while read line
do

scp  -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no  test.file user-B@(IP-Server-B):/home/user-B
ssh -t  user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t  scp  -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no test.file mtc@$line:/home/mtc
ssh -t  user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t  ssh  -t -tqn user-c@$line sh /home/user-c/test.file
ssh -t  user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t  scp  user-c@$line:/home/user-c/junk.txt /home/user-B
ssh -t  user-B@(IP-Server-B) -t  ssh  user-c@$line rm -rf /home/user-c/junk.txt
scp  user-B@(IP-Server-B):/home/user-B/junk.txt .
mv junk.txt junk.txt_$line

done < LabIpList
```

Here is the list of IP address of servers Server-c...Server-L.

```
cat LabIpList


1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
4.5.6.7
5.6.7.8
6.7.8.9
7.8.9.10
....
.....
```

## Query:

If I do above commands on command line then they work flawlessly, however If I put them on script then they fail. Because of two reasons :

1. tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
2. pseudo-terminal will not be allocated
3. As the SSH-keys are recently exchanged , so user have to manually type yes to add them to know_hosts.

Comment: And what is the question? Did you read about `ssh_config`, where you can configure all that bloat you just coded into your script?

Comment: How to manage to pass , manual authentication for new ssh keys + run SSH commands through shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already created passwordless login using ssh-keygen.Please use below options for ssh in the script

```
ssh -t -t -tq <IP>
```